# Firebase Security Rules always false on get() or exists() operation PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I finished making my app and I'm implementing the security rules.
I am currently trying to validate whether or not a user exists in the bank, if he exists, he will be able to read and write to a specific path. I'm using Firestore:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents{

    match /Usuarios/{documentID} {  
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == documentID;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null; 
        

     match /Manejo/{manejoID} {
         allow write, read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.auth.uid)); // The id is never exist... even when it does exist in my database, this operation simply DOES NOT WORK despite the document with the Uid existing in the database
     }
    
    }
    
  
}
```

Edit1:

```
match /Manejo/{manejoID} {
         allow write, read: if true; 
    }
```

This condition not work too...

Comment: When I try to use get () using the same path and taking any field and arriving if it is different from "empty" the operation is also denied, I feel that he can't even reach the document.

Comment: "Manejo" is a subCollection of document User specific

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, don't leave those as comments - simply edit the question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare in which collection you want to check the existence of the doc with `docId == userId`

With

```
allow write, read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.auth.uid));
```

you don't declare the collection.

Look at the following example in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents), which checks for the existence of the doc with `docId == userId` **in the `users` collection**. See how `/users/` is added right after `$(database)/documents`.

```
allow create: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
```

---

I understand that want to check the existence of the doc in the `Usuarios` collection. If this assumption is correct, do as follows:

```
allow write, read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Usuarios/$(request.auth.uid));
```

---

Note that you may be interested by this Firebase blog [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/firebase-security-rules-admin-sdk-tips.html).

Comment: Hello, I tried to do it and even then the app did not enter the subcollection condition, I assume that the error is with Firebase, as it cannot approve the creation of documents in the collection even if I put "if true". But your answer is correct for the errors in the question.

Comment: If it is a subcollection you need to add the **entire path** to the rule. Something like the following: `allow write, read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/PatentCollection/$(DocID)/Usuarios/$(request.auth.uid));`. You need to point to the exact location of the document you to check the existence.

Comment: Also if you consider that my answer correctly answers the question, as you mentioned above, please accept and upvote it. Thanks.